# Creating a plain table in Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I wanted to utilize parts of the Ext JS library to render plain table but based on a data store and record model. Do you know of any tutorials and/or other resources that would help me out getting started with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render a "plain HTML table", why do you need record model?

One (and easiest) approach would be to make an AJAX call (preferably using [Ext Direct](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect/)), and apply [XTemplate](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.XTemplate) to the returned JSON result.

Two other approaches would be -

1. Use the light weight [list view](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/view/list-view.html) component instead of grid (if light weight is your concnern)
2. Style the grid or list view component to "look like" plain HTML table.

Comment: The thing is that I already have a bunch of stuff that depends on a particular feature of the grid that's not available in Ext and that's why I wanted to create a custom grid control for it. For example every data row consists of 2 table rows whereas the second row is invisible by default and if "expanded" it loads details (sort of a master-detail thing).

Comment: Anyways - thanks for the info - I'll try out the XTemplate thingy and see if that'll work for me.

Comment: For nested info under the master rows, take a look at the first example on the grid plugins example page - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html